# Running AWS serverless with NestJS without main file throws an error

Tags: docker, nestjs, aws-serverless

I'm trying to run serverless app via docker. The app uses NestJS framework. Here is the partial file structure:

```
|--apps
   |--common
      |--src
         |--models
            |--...some models files here
            |--...
         |--resources
            |--...some resources files here
            |--...
         |--utils
            |--...some utils files here
            |--...
      |--tsconfig.app.json
   |--users
      |--src
         |--models
            |--...some models files here
            |--...
         |--main.ts
         |--models.provider.ts
         |--users.controller.ts
         |--users.module.ts
         |--users.service.ts
      |--tsconfig.app.json
|--Makefile
|--nest-cli.json
|--package.json
|--template.yaml
|--tsconfig.build.json
|--tsconfig.json
```

Makefile:

```yaml
.PHONY: build-RuntimeDependenciesLayer
.PHONY: build-UsersFunction

build-RuntimeDependenciesLayer:
    mkdir -p "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs"
    cp package.json package-lock.json "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/"
    npm install --production --prefix "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/"
    npm install -g modclean
    echo yes | modclean -n default:safe --path="$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/"
    rm "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/package.json"
    cp ".env.$(NODE_ENV)" "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/.env.$(NODE_ENV)"
    cp -r "locales" "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/locales"
    npm install -g @nestjs/cli
    npm install

build-lambda-common:
    rm -rf dist
    nest build $(ENTITY)
    cp -r dist "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/"

build-UsersFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=apps/users/src/main.ts ENTITY=users build-lambda-common
```

nest-cli.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/common/src",
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "apps/common",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "webpack": false,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/common/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "projects": {
    "common": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/common",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/common/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/common/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/users",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/users/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/users/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I build everything with command

```
nest build
```

Then for running it in docker I use two commands in separate terminal windows:

```
NODE_ENV=local sam local start-api --docker-network <network_name> --warm-containers LAZY
NODE_ENV=local sam local start-lambda --docker-network <network_name> --warm-containers LAZY --host localhost
```

Everything builds correctly, but when I'm trying to do a GET request to **/users** route, I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'main'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'main'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)","    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)"
```

If I do it without docker, using command `nest start`, I get almost the same error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/app/dist/apps/common/main'
```

Looks like the **main.ts** file doesn't exist in **common** module can be the reason. How should I organise common utilities in this case? Or may be I miss something else.

Comment: @CodeBy yes, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. Entities should be built one by one, instead of trying to build all together. I added a script for that:

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const readdir = util.promisify(require('fs').readdir);

const build = async () => {
  try {
    const names = await readdir('apps');
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
      const name = names[i];
      await exec(`nest build ${name}`);
      console.log(`${name} is built`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

void build();
```